# Please Read Primes

Tags: code-golf, string, primes

Do you know the book *Murderous Maths*, in the *Horrible Science* series? In the book, the Laplace Princess' "ridiculous" cipher might be interesting enough and simple enough to be a code-golf challenge.

## Task

The original cipher looks like this:

> Please read primes elephant help you me like cold

The nth word is only meaningful if it is a prime. So, the cipher becomes:

> read primes help me

Your task is to write a program that inputs the cipher and outputs the plaintext.

## Rules

- You can take the input in any acceptable forms, e. g. an list of words.
- The input will only consist of printable-ASCII characters.
- You can use 0-based index or 1-based index.
- A "Word" includes any punctuation. For example:

  ```
  This is, "a" great test! I think.
  ```

  should output

  ```
  is, "a" test! think.
  ```

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-f`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>6</s> 2 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

I/O as arrays of words with 0-based indexing

```
Vj
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWY&code=Vmo&input=WyJQbGVhc2UiLCJyZWFkIiwicHJpbWVzIiwiZWxlcGhhbnQiLCJoZWxwIiwieW91IiwibWUiLCJsaWtlIiwiY29sZC4uLiJdCi1T)

```
Vj     :Implicit filter of input array
V      :0-based index of current word
 j     :Is prime?
```

---

### Japt `-S`, 4 bytes

I/O as space-delimited strings, with 0-based indexing

```
¸fÏj
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVM&code=uGbPag&input=IlBsZWFzZSByZWFkIHByaW1lcyBlbGVwaGFudCBoZWxwIHlvdSBtZSBsaWtlIGNvbGQuLi4i)

```
¸fÏj     :Implicit input of string
¸        :Split on spaces
 f       :Filter by
  Ï      :  0-based index
   j     :  Is prime?
         :Implicit output, joined by spaces
```

---

### Japt `-S`, 6 bytes

I/O as space-delimited strings, with 1-based indexing

```
¸fÏÄ j
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVM&code=uGbPxCBq&input=IlBsZWFzZSByZWFkIHByaW1lcyBlbGVwaGFudCBoZWxwIHlvdSBtZSBsaWtlIGNvbGQuLi4i)

Same as above using `Ä` to add `1` to the index.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

```
#āpÏðý
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f@UhjweH@wxsO7/3/PyAnNbE4VaEoNTFFoaAoMze1WCE1J7UgIzGvRCEjNadAoTK/VCE3VSEnMztVITk/J0VPTw8A)

```
#         # split the input on spaces
 ā        # push [1..length of the list of words]
  p       # is prime?
   Ï      # keep only words where the above check is true
    ðý    # join with spaces
```

Comment: Wow. What could you do with a kilobyte of 05AB1E code?

Comment: @JL2210 not that much. 05AB1E is really good at small challenges, but it doesn't scale well: no functions, limited number of variables, etc.

Comment: [3 bytes, just accepting the words](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//SGPB4f7//6OVAnJSE4tTlXSUilITU4BUQVFmbmoxkJGak1qQkZhXAmRmpOYUAKnK/FIgmQtSnJOZDaKS83NS9PT0lGIB "05AB1E – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 22 bytes

```perl6
*[grep &is-prime,2..*]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcoxCgIxEAXQ3lN8tthi0YAWNuId7MUimL9ucGKGGUVy@izsq5/S5NxLwzjj2qf7y6gYsx/UcuH@FML06Jedx4YZwzHgJoxOGGPCdhwU6hI/XywURas/FELym3hWSUP4V0veVw)

Takes input as a list of words and outputs the zero indexed list.

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 201 bytes

Input is zero indexed.

```
fun p(s:Int):MutableList<Int>{val l=MutableList(0){0}
o@
for(v in 2..s){for(e in l)if(v%e<1)continue@o
l.add(v)}
return l}
fun main(){var w=readLine()!!.split(" ")
for(i in p(w.size))print("${w[i]} ")}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVVhayM3EP3uXzExPboGZx1fP7Q1SZvj2l4DCRzJQSlHKfLu2CuslbaSNo7P@LenM6OV4xSOfjFr6WnmzZs30sZFo@3zbAY3tuvjAkKnKoSAnfIqYg1b5@sAzoICAmI5IuinBod15RG@oHegbY1PWJcj3n/vUc6unIfY6ACVqxHWzqygapQxaNe4YGATYxcWsxnv83YZoqo2@EQogpSVa2f/zOY/fjf/4XuGfzSoAsI9qho@et1iAMn3i4Od62Fj3ZbyISyd28Bd72ti1ge4U7EJU6LIWN7/3XmvlwbhodJopVyvMfxMGhzPTzP4VnWGJaGEBA3hWxh7XeuqNxR7DJXuGvQMbvW6ibBEShTRY4jargGt69cNKFtD0G1nkJHDYnSMVqLO@Wt1ko6fVNiMsuDO67W2ygwZwRDJQD3ZoGi8GJ0o5FmhLimEBjuSM0KDphOdWiEhJytn6mMGGxtpK2huuNkRUFkqYtUb0CvQkTYYq1LoEh7cVCQaGC2RGoYDk1MKkpmy8vqfridTUGGchRTYeh1RQrq1Vy3FU5SHvRhyB4bwrKHrI@/IMrWFlX6KSaz73mDIKaBS1Eol2mAKR78UYgeqqrCLaplaQRZtyRtUzLqkbVIlRHCrZO/yKE2KsNXGJGUqZ8OApBqthDtn8LuH9zc33EevKnLBECIz6qk3F@dLalGdJoa6CvPThYR/B@M/iMCY1irT1yQhM@96W8VeRe1sCb85MR0@KXbVIhElSTVVM1ZjWPMMQiQbnsENO8RuSmBUaFxvspK8kE8kbEbyzq9PHYnOg8yZKS0pQB6hLrdoo7SvUoYmgaY9N2toOWni5MoI1B46PqwXQX/BBc1ZnCxoQkW3W8Jc0spPsB@NACjOXW6cdAPbLu6kYIhbB72NmrqwSlDbt0vyRu7YlEYZB7Me51ElaDItfT/SEEnkq1MKxcUE9nABB0KQOOiv6YNvsILwPVsA3pYl858kohKUWSl2xeq0eiJhIThYKT/NSCLF1q9670k8GILSfD4iOSqjav2oAynNrGC5kyMSdEr3J3kv40hdzmfJ/ilUKTvClyae@8OMucyJ7AATSKW8yYBLmOdNYEvTjdXjtRR/LPAm0U501xh5mj2xYYH7wPpm5HAtcN2qrhlAJPlsMgGj5Is2Ew/OfYA0hEPn7zH23r5UHficT4t8eHQ4djK8tmhLl8FXfFrKi5EN@mrCYeVdK8s0mp4eP6P52masS2@BvIcU4gPGwc/D0HOfOU16VphxiphewpAMi6pqcv9qTeHVLvNgdBoNpv53wa5ib@Y4V3KF3tKbW0zOzkqhVoxhPMm2TBeIPo5WurLEoKmrcjMV42/2svNZ8H8dOIKoKGnTqzHcvfJMc@yTd4i2317MyYp0PTzLIBdhIfP73/Hdy1xdvR6p/cVh5K5HFLR4zCM02fNfmSgz0avi8Q1ezicv/huZ5JHJYZRbfzgKVUz2otHV19Th2FpkKbaDGi9CfNYiwOH5eXgpa/e/j@XLS/kv)

Comment: +1 for using a verbose language.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>125</s> 107 bytes

107 bytes thanks to Black Owl Kai

```python
i=input().split();j=k=1
for c in i:
 if j>1:
  while k>2:
   k-=1
   if j%k<1:k=0
  if k:print(c)
 j+=1;k=j
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYpBDoIwEEX3nOJvTCBGY3UHljN4BQJDOp3SNlBiOH0trt5/eT8eyQT/ypk1@7inurlv0XFhZ7VoVc1hxQj24LYCz7C9KgNfw44g/fMUyK08C89@kbdqRT@qv0obV/apHpsK9qpVJ9rm/HE0bISVhgmlL7SBHEUz@ARDLuIIOxaCYyGMwU0/)

120 bytes if it strictly follows rules.
-25 bytes thanks to Black Owl Kai

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>145</s> 120 bytes

```python
i=input().split();j=k=1;l=[]
for c in i:
 if j>1:
  while k>2:
   k-=1
   if j%k<1:k=0
  if k:l+=[c]
 j+=1;k=j
print(*l)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYxBDoIwFET3PcVsTECisboDyxncExYEPuHTT2mgxHD6Cq7evJlk/B6G2b1iZMPObyFJ76sXPliMxhpdiKlq1c8LWrAD5wrcYyz1EfAdWAi2fJ4CezP65Llf7Fvn1jzUX20umanaWmHMjktrRuUXdiG5ShrjR6hZCQs1HY56ohUk5IfGBQwkHvu8YSIIW0I7S/cD)

Comment: If a trailing space is acceptable, you can shorten your longer solution to the shorter one with `print(c,end=' ')`. If this is not the case, you can at least shorten the last line to `print(*l)`

Comment: Also, you can delete line 3 if you change line 4 to `if j>1` (in both versions)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
LÆRị
```

A monadic Link accepting a list of words which yields a list of words.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/ncFvQw93d/w@3a@s/alpzdNLDnTP@/49WD8nILFbXUVDPLNYBUUqJSiAqvSg1sQTEKEktLlEEMTzBvIzMvGz1WAA)** (the footer calls the Link then formats, since a full-program implicitly smashes output)

#### How?

```
LÆRị - Link: list, W
L    - length (W)
 ÆR  - inclusive prime range = [2,3,5,7,...,Prime <= length(W)]
   ị - index into (W)
```

---

Also 4:

```
JẒƇị
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 167 bytes

```php
<?php $i=explode(' ',$argv[1]);$l=count($i);unset($i[0]);for($x=1;$x<$l;$x++){$y=$x+1;$z=2;while($z<$y){$t=$y/$z;if($t==(int)$t)unset($i[$x]);$z++;}}echo join(' ',$i);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7BCsIwEER/ZQ8LJlTQek2Dv@C9eCjtaqJrEtpU20q/PUYEL8NjBmYmmJBSdQwmAFpNU2DfkdjAZotNf33W5VkqZN360UWBVqrRDfSlep@Ti@8FTrpUOFXIWYtCvnHWGbK36IN6GcskcKlwzknUOO9wUfYiMmthXZQY5b8Tp@/cUhRqXak1Hm7eut@bPJ1SOjE1A0FPTQehtw8agJiCaVwEQxxg9iM8CNjeCVrP3Qc)

#### Ungolfed:

```php
<?php

$input = explode(' ', $argv[1]);
$length = count($input);
unset($input[0]);

for($x = 1; $x < $length; $x++) {
    $y = $x + 1;
    $z = 2;

    while($z < $y) {
        $test = $y / $z;

        if($test == (int) $test) {
            unset($input[$x]);
        }

        $z++;
    }
}

echo join(' ', $input);

?>
```

Comment: Using your own idea, I golfed it more to 127 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU/BSsQwEL37FXOIbEKVtee0eFrR05ayN5GltrNNNJsJk1a7@/HGFEEYeMzMe7z3ggmpegwm3CAz8ZExEE/Wj3J33LXtvlUatls4GBshD3l3AYOM8I59N0eEw8semucGvpCjJb@Svpn8mISre5r9JIWtcQmOBpQb2NyJjkevlJ59xPX5@vCm9IlYarEURSVcRrXu4lqXuijEtarFopU9SZkZpbrNl1L9y8WS9dgbgg@y/s/CKp1S47DLARm7AQLbM0ZAh8F0fsoVXIALzXBGcPYToSc3/FCYcoWY7p9@AQ "PHP – Try It Online"), I suspect that using other solutions that won't need `unset` it should be more golf-able.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 90 bytes

```python
print(*[w for n,w in enumerate(input().split()[1:])if all((n+2)%i for i in range(2,n+2))])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc1NasMwEAXgvU/xMASkNpSMnH/oHbpPs1DrcSwqj4UsE3J6V3Y2Wc1jmPdNeKS2l2pqPr3tfmp7/p5CdJLU2@WOpo@Q9R1OwDJ2HG1i5SSMSemPIXiX54XOV@0aWO@VknejV27pubkVrdxYmfW811c9NUoXT76MbGvk3PGAln1Ax6UuXg4MKuxwABGoAuVwKvX05dkOjNc2ew6tlfRkHv2YKXj3x/jtfV0QZmmbrX3WjjiBNgtqFncL2oH2y4Nj/gGz@Qc)

Answer (score 1):

## Rust, 339 bytes

First ever submission to Code Golf, but it works!

```
use std::io;use std::io::BufRead;fn main(){println!("{}",io::BufReader::new(io::stdin().lock()).lines().flat_map(|s|s.unwrap().split_whitespace().map(|s|s.to_owned()).collect::<Vec<String>>()).enumerate().filter(|(x,_)|{if *x<2{return false}for i in 2..*x{if x%i==0{return false}};true}).map(|(_,y)|y).collect::<Vec<String>>().join(" "));}
```

This code is compressed down from this:

```
use std::io;
use std::io::BufRead;
use std::io::BufReader;

fn main() {
    let s = BufReader::new(io::stdin().lock())
        .lines()
        .flat_map(|s| {
            s.unwrap()
                .split_whitespace()
                .map(|s| s.to_owned())
                .collect::<Vec<String>>()
        })
        .enumerate()
        .filter(|(x,_)| {
            if *x<2 {
                return false
            }
            for i in 2..*x {
                if x % i == 0 {
                    return false
                }
            };
            true
        })
        .map(|(_,y)| y)
        .collect::<Vec<String>>()
        .join(" ");
    println!("{}", &s);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Well done!

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-p -rprime`, 36 bytes

Replaces every word (and the space after it, if present) with the empty string if it is a non-prime word.

```ruby
i=0
gsub(/\S+ ?/){$&if(i+=1).prime?}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcyxDoIwFEbhnaf4JcZAUNAHIMxsJjq6FLnSGwptestAjK9uNawn@Y5fujVGrs/JIEuXVY9bgabK3/sDvzIu6kteOs8TNZ8Yr4aUEDypHlsUkCGn1RygyTisdsFEMDwSntb0yV2zgOWIVKUY/jAgkIQdWgTN81h@rQtsZ4kn57flDw)

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 95 bytes

```c
#define f(w,n)for(int i=0,j,p[n]={};++i<n;p[i]||printf("%s ",w[i]))for(j=i*i;j<n;j+=i)p[j]=i>1;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZDBbsMgDIbvPIXFNCk0TGq1I2MvEuVQpaYx6kxEaJmW5tkz2HaZNh8M5v/8C3t4Og/Dtj2c0BEjuCZrVi7EhjgB2b32euq4t8tq2pZe2Ewd9ff7FIvuGvk4g9S5PKmvJm9pR8YXzLeW1NT53tLrwWxiGI9xBznE09z1YGGRHxiD1DIwlpxyvacxYqkE/ArpwjUW1dGtojO9/0VmvCEXEek8pnIy8T9G6Zu5/MAp46VYrkbUqAO/HYkbBYuoi6h/1YdnUFWHiOkaGfZGrNsn)

Sieve of E.

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/) + gmp, 48 bytes

```r
(W=scan(,'',,,,''))[gmp::isprime(1:length(W))>0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY2xCsIwFEV/5dolCZSia0EHN3ehgzik9pE8NK8leSJ@fWy94zkcbq7VDsfy8GJbY9p1xjh3C2npey5L5kT20L9IgkY7OHfa3@s1cgGXFo1vEDJ5hVLRHS7QyPLscH4rkv@OhA9BiCboDI/XLIEyinqlRKIb3UpEDnEV5v9XDHwmjMQSMM1CXf0B)

This use `gmp` for the `isprime` builtin.  This returns 0, 1 or 2, hence the test for > 0.  `scan` takes the input as characters split on whitespace and quotes set to empty string.

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 8 bytes

```
⌈'&›¥æ;Ṅ
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E2%8C%88%27%26%E2%80%BA%C2%A5%C3%A6%3B%E1%B9%84&inputs=Please%20read%20primes%20elephant%20help%20you%20me%20like%20cold&header=&footer=)

```
⌈        # Split on spaces
 '    ;  # Filter by 
  &›     # Increment register
    ¥æ   # Register prime?
       Ṅ # Join on spaces
```